# Split string from multiple line

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I have the following code to split strings in arrays and then instert the arrays into database

```
Private Sub ReadAllModules()
    Dim list As String() = rtbComData.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    For Each Row As String In list
        If Not (Row = "AT+BC=FL " + dtp_Rinterval.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "" Or Row = "OK" Or Row = "") Then
            Try
                Dim separator As String() = {"+", "|", "*"}
                Dim s = Row.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                Dim con As New SqlConnection
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\smdData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
                con.Open()
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE smdTable SET date='" + s(1) + "',datetime='" + s(2) + "',Interval1='" + s(3) + "',vi1='" + s(4) + "',Interval2='" + s(5) + "',vi2='" + s(6) + "',Interval3='" + s(7) + "' WHERE AdresaUnica= '" + s(0) + "'"

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Me.SmdTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Until now I had the strings coming on a single line and that was ok. However now my strings comes on different lines like:

```
AT+BC=FL 09/09/2015
OK
+00019500000068B9|1:9/9/2015|06:55:18|19:30-22:30*100|22:30-00:30*80|00:30-       05:00*40|05:00-

+00019500000068B9|2:07:30*90|OFF
```

how do I insert the second line string in an array and insert it in the database?

Comment: kindly format your question

Comment: What do you mean it `comes on different lines`? What do you do to see it *come on different lines*? Sounds like an issue of how you are displaying it. If you split the string into parts, now it is 5 or 6 or 7 smaller strings

Comment: You have to identify some consistent pattern, or "row" delimiters, to the data you are reading. Once you have identified a row you'll need to massage the string until it can be processed. You could try posting more current raw data, and the original raw data, so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` consist of more than one char. Try doing this instead: `Dim list As String() = rtbComData.Text.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)`